# Can we create sub context for domain component entry in openLDAP using Java?

Tags: java, openldap

I am trying to create sub context for domain component, 
but its showing the following error

javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge]; remaining name 'uid=user3, dc=example'

This is my Code

public class OpenLDAPTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "ldap://localhost:389";
    // String url = "ldap://localhost:10389";
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
    // env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin, ou=system");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("connected");
        System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());
        System.out.println("Creating subContext");
        String name = "uid=user3, dc=example";
        Attributes atrs = new BasicAttributes();
        Attribute atr1 = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
        atr1.add("inetOrgPerson");
        atrs.put(atr1);
        Attribute atr2 = new BasicAttribute("cn");
        atr2.add("sathish");
        atrs.put(atr2);
        Attribute atr3 = new BasicAttribute("o");
        atr3.add("Kumar");
        atrs.put(atr3);
        Attribute atr4 = new BasicAttribute("sn");
        atr4.add("example");
        atrs.put(atr4);
        Context c = ctx.createSubcontext(name, atrs);
        System.out.println(c.getEnvironment());
        ctx.close();

    } catch (AuthenticationNotSupportedException ex) {
        System.out
                .println("The authentication is not supported by the server");
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        System.out.println("incorrect password or username");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        // System.out.println("error when trying to create the context");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

If I use the same code for ApacheDS(by changing credentials) its working. but its not working for openLDAP.

Comment: You should not use the Manager account for anything. That's for `slapd.exe` itself. You should create an administrative account inside the DIT that has the appopriate privileges.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it.

Comment: Why? when you can look it up for yourself in the documentation?

Comment: I am not that much good in LDAP, I am just using it now only... which doc I have to prefer, in net I am getting so many docs, none of them providing proper solution

Comment: Rubbish. Everything I know about LDAP and OpenLDAP came from the documentation, specifcally including how to create administrative accounts. If you can't deal with the official documentation you don't have much future in this business.

Comment: Its not rubbish Mr, I don't need that much in depth knowledge on LDAP & OPEN LDAP, in my current project I am need this much only, next I may get another requirement with another technology, I don't want to get complete knowledge in each & every technology, in fact no one is that much talented person. If you can, then help me otherwise leave it. Don't say its rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to **set the domain name  as 'dc=example' upon installation**

in the LDAP backend setting step,

[image: ldap setting]
<sub>(source: [userbooster.de](https://www.userbooster.de/images/cont/articles/openldap-for-windows/LDAP-backend.png))</sub>

otherwise you could **change "uid=user3, dc=example" to "uid=user3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"** to add it .

Don't bother yourself adding a database with root "dc=example" while there is already a database with root "dc=maxrc,dc=com" in windows server.

**Update:**

Though you set domain to be "dc=maxcrc,dc=com",corresponding domain root entry is not added by default.

You need to add "dc=maxcrc,dc=com"  before adding that sub context

```
    String name = "dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
    Attributes atrs = new BasicAttributes();
    Attribute atr1 = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    atr1.add("organization");
    atrs.put(atr1);
    Attribute atr2 = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    atr2.add("dcObject");
    atrs.put(atr2);
    Attribute atr3 = new BasicAttribute("dc");
    atr3.add("maxcrm");
    atrs.put(atr3);
    Attribute atr4 = new BasicAttribute("o");
    atr4.add("anyOrgYouLike");
    atrs.put(atr4);
    Context c = ctx.createSubcontext(name, atrs);
```

Comment: perhaps for apache ds its root dn related to domain component is "dc=example" by default.

Comment: I replaced "uid=user3, dc=example" with "uid=user3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" , I am getting the following error

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'uid=user3,dc=maxcrc,dc=com'

Comment: Thanks for your help fenixan, But still its again giving the following error

javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - no structural object class provided]; remaining name 'dc=maxcrc,dc=com'

Comment: @Sathish I just corrected a mistake in my code adding the entry,you may try again if you didn't find that;otherwise you could try adding this entry via an ldap windows client...

Comment: thanks for  supporting Fenixan, I am still getting the errors, I uninstalled OpenLDAP & installed it again, previously I chosen BDB as backend setting but this time while installing I chosen LDAP as backend setting but still getting the error.
Error:
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: [LDAP: error code 52 - Proxy operation retry failed]

Changed Pricipal :
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=name,cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com");

Comment: It seems you will work on this subject for quite a long time,you may refer to the link above to get through LDAP concepts and configuration,otherwise there will be millions of errors...

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting amounts to creating a new database in OpenLDAP called `dc=example`. You can only do that via configuration.

Comment: I did explain clearly and I do not appreciate being told otherwise. You need to create a database called `dc=example` via the configuration, which only restates what I have already said.

Comment: I have installed openLDAP in windows, I dont know how to run it, in the back ground its running but where to write LDAP commands?